# Binding listbox to object without window datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to bind my listbox to an object without the wpf window binding to a datacontext:

```
<ListBox Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="lstb_logFiles" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" SelectionChanged="lstb_threadList_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dateName,StringFormat=\{0\}}" Foreground="Orange" Margin="10,3,0,3" Width="80" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And here is where I setup the binding

```
public ObservableCollection<FileLog> _logFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileLog>();
lstb_logFiles.DataContext = _logFiles;
```

This doesn't work, my _logFiles definitely have object in it, but lstb_logFiles does not show any items.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318601/using-itemssource-to-populate-wpf-listbox-good-idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ListBox` to populate its item, you should set `ItemsSource` and not `DataContext`.

It should be:

```
lstb_logFiles.ItemsSource = _logFiles;
```

and not

```
lstb_logFiles.DataContext = _logFiles;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the itemssource to "self"

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

or instead of setting the datacontext you can set the itemssource directly

```
  public ObservableCollection<FileLog> _logFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileLog>();
  lstb_logFiles.ItemsSource= _logFiles;
```